# How would I move my node up when there is a touch and hold on the screen in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: xcode, swift, touchesbegan

When the user touches the screen and holds it, I'd like the `SKSpriteNode` to fly up, and after user stops holding touch, it again falls down to the ground. Right now I'm using tapping to move the node up and setting the gravity to false in the touchesEnded to make it fall to the ground. How would I get this to work. Thanks!

```
   var touchingScreen = false

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = true
}


    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = false
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = false
}

 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if touchingScreen {
        // Adjust the CGVector to suit your needs.
        heroNode.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 10))


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly,** you need to keep track of when the user is touching and holding the screen. You can do this like so, in your `SKScene`:

```
var touchingScreen = false

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = true
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = false
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = false
}
```

**Secondly,** you now need to make the object move upwards whilst the user is pressing the screen, again in your `SKScene`:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if touchingScreen {
        // Adjust the CGVector to suit your needs.
        sprite.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want your object to move upwards at a constant velocity, replace:

```
sprite.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
```

with

```
sprite.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: yourDx, dy: yourDy)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out when I get home!

Comment: It just goes straight up and when I let go it doesnt go back down.

Comment: You need to make sure `heroNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true`, that could be the problem?

Comment: That works but the touch and hold doesnt work. It only responds to taps.

Comment: its not coming back down also when I let go of the screen it just continues to go upward. I have the affectedByGravity set to true in the touchesEnded.

Comment: By default `affectedByGravity` is set to `true`. You don't need to set it to anything in order for the code above to work. Try removing any code that is setting `affectedByGravity`.

Comment: I got rid of the affectedByGravity and the node is just moving upward with one tap and not coming down.

Comment: Can you post the code for your `SKScene` as an edit to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76113/discussion-between-abakersmith-and-newtocoding).